# HTTP request using x-www-form-urlencoded in PL/SQL procedure

Tags: rest, plsql, twilio, oracle-apex

I am trying to create an http request that sends a body as x-www-form-urlencoded with PL/SQL.
how do I create the body for the request?
The body should be a key value pair such as:
To=+1303123123
From=+13039998888

```
    l_request_body := ???

    APEX_WEB_SERVICE.g_request_headers(1).name := 'Content-Type';
    APEX_WEB_SERVICE.g_request_headers(1).value :=  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

    APEX_WEB_SERVICE.g_request_headers(2).name := 'Authorization';
    APEX_WEB_SERVICE.g_request_headers(2).value := 'Basic xxxxx';

    l_response := APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_rest_request(
    p_url             =\> l_url,
    p_http_method     =\> 'POST',
    p_body            =\> l_request_body
    );
```

The request should use the APEX_WEB_SERVICE package.